# What is the role of the spread operator in this javascript code?

Tags: javascript, arrays, syntax, set, spread-syntax

Today I read [this article](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/9-extremely-powerful-javascript-hacks-eed8ed11af5) in medium, and I don't understand about spread operator below.

[image]

I know that the spread operator is used to receive array as a parameter in a function. In the code above, what does the spread operator do? Convert object to array?

Comment: spread is not an operator.

Comment: Have you read the [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) about spread? Obviously not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know that the spread operator is used to receive array as a
> parameter in a function

In that context, three dots `...` are referred to as [`rest parameters syntax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters), not [`spread syntax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). In the code included in your question, the context in which three dots `...` are used, it is known as [`spread syntax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

> In the code above, what does the spread operator do?

It iterates over the `Set` and *spreads* (adds) the entries in the `Set` in to a new array

Following code snippet shows a simple example:

```js
const set = new Set([1,2,3]);
const newArr = [...set];

console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: Thanks for comment. I understand that `...` has two different syntax.

Answer (score 1):

The spread operator, in combination with the array syntax (`[]`) takes the values from the Set and, for lack of better term, spreads them out, so you get an array with all the values in the Set. The end result is that you transform an array to another array that holds the unique values from the original array.

Answer (score 1):

Lets look at it line by line.

`var entries = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 4, 2, 1]`

This creates an array `entries` with some list of numbers.

Now when we do, `new Set(entries)`, we create a `Set` from `entries` array.
A `Set` is a collection of distinct elements as you may already know.

Hence, `new Set(entries)` gives us a `Set` from `entries` as follows:
`Set(8) {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, …}`

Now, `...` operator spreads the distinct elements from the `Set` to create an array, which is the line - `var unique_entries = [...new Set(entries)]`

Comment: Thanks for comment. I understand now!